# How can I get a finish button after a nsDialogs page

Tags: nsis

I'm trying to create a post install configuration page in my nsis script using nsDialogs.  My script for gathering the input and executing the configuration works however I'm never presented with a finish/close/exit button after I'm done.  Currently my pages declaration looks like:

```
Page directory
Page instfiles
Page custom nsDialogsPage nsDialogsPageLeave
```

How can I get a finish/exit/done button to show after nsDialogsPageLeave executes?

Comment: The classic NSIS UI (aka Not using Modern UI) does not have a finish page, do you want a separate finish page or just change the name of the button on your custom page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The classic NSIS UI does not have a finish page, the instfiles page is usually the last page and it will show a "finish button" after all the sections have executed. You can set the text of any button to the same string with `SendMessage $hwndButton ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:$(^CloseBtn)"` if you want to provide your own finish page.

Most installers request the required information before the instfiles page, if you cannot do this then you might want to use the [Modern UI](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Modern%20UI/Readme.html), it will provide a finish page for you:

```
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
Page custom nsDialogsPage nsDialogsPageLeave
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
```

It was a little unclear to me if you wanted two pages; a input page and then a finish page or a combined input/finish page. A combined page is a little weird but it is possible:

```
!define AppName "Test"
Name "${AppName}"
Outfile "${AppName} setup.exe"
InstallDir $temp

!include LogicLib.nsh
!include WinMessages.nsh
!include nsDialogs.nsh

Var MyEndConfigPageStage

Page Directory
Page InstFiles
Page Custom MyEndConfigPageCreate MyEndConfigPageLeave /EnableCancel

Function MyEndConfigPageCreate
StrCpy $MyEndConfigPageStage 0
GetDlgItem $0 $hwndparent 1
SendMessage $0 ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:&Apply"
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0
${NSD_CreateCheckBox} 0 13u 100% -13u "FooBar"
Pop $1
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function MyEndConfigPageLeave
${If} $MyEndConfigPageStage > 0
    Return
${EndIf}
${NSD_GetState} $1 $2
ClearErrors
WriteIniStr "$instdir\settings.ini" Dummy "FooBar" $2
${If} ${Errors}
    MessageBox mb_iconstop "Unable to apply settings!"
    Abort
${EndIf}
IntOp $MyEndConfigPageStage $MyEndConfigPageStage + 1
GetDlgItem $0 $hwndparent 1
SendMessage $0 ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:$(^CloseBtn)"
GetDlgItem $0 $hwndparent 2
EnableWindow $0 0 ;Disable cancel
EnableWindow $1 0 ;Disable the checkbox
Abort
FunctionEnd

Section
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Yeah, I ended up moving the config screen before insfiles.  However I'm looking into trying to convert the whole thing over to Modern UI.